# MATLAB: errorn in butter() command

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I wrote the following function:

```
function [output_signal] = AddDirectivityError (bat_loc_index, butter_deg_vector, sound_matrix)

    global chirp_initial_freq ;
    global chirp_end_freq;
    global sampling_rate;
    global num_of_mics; 
    global sound_signal_length;
    for (i=1 : num_of_mics)
        normalized_co_freq = (chirp_initial_freq + chirp_end_freq)/ (1.6* sampling_rate);
        A=sound_matrix  ( i, :  )  ;
        peak_signal=max(A);
        B=find(abs(A)>peak_signal/100);
        if (butter_deg_vector(i)==0)
            butter_deg_vector(i)=2;
        end
        [num, den] = butter(butter_deg_vector(i), normalized_co_freq, 'low');// HERE!!!
        filtered_signal=filter(num,den, A );
        output_signal(i, :)=filtered_signal;
    end
```

This functions runs many-many times without any error. However, when I reach the line: `[num, den] = butter ( butter_deg_vector(i), normalized_co_freq, 'low');`

And the local variables are: `i=3, butter_deg_vector(i)=1, normalized_co_freq=5.625000e-001`

MATLAB prompts an error says:

```
??? Error using ==> buttap Expected N to be integer-valued.

"Error in ==> buttap at 15 validateattributes(n,{'numeric'},{'scalar','integer','positive'},'buttap','N');

Error in ==> butter at 70 [z,p,k] = buttap(n);"
```

I don't understand why this problem occurs especially in this iteration. Why does this function prompt an error especially in this case?

Comment: Can you type `whos` when this error occurs? Because, it seems that `butter_deg_vector` does not contain integers...

Comment: type "whos"? what does it mean?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/whos.html

Comment: It seems that you are not providing an `int`, but a `float`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the code line for:

```
[num, den] = butter (round(butter_deg_vector(i)), normalized_co_freq, 'low');
```